LOD with Boolean expression
I have a parameter in a report to display exposure amount for a customer with or without closed deals.
For ex: Display exposure amount with closed deals or without closed deals.
I am struggling to incorporate this open/close flag within my existing calculation.
Below is the formula i use to calculate exposure for a customer:
i.e. I want to add a condition (Open/Close flag) to this existing formula to calculate total exposure with closed deals or without closed deals.
Appreciate your suggestion.
ifnull(
sum(
IF 
{ FIXED [Customer], [Deal], [Schedule]:
COUNTD([Buyback])} > 0
then 
{ FIXED [Customer], [Deal], [Schedule]:
AVG(ifnull([Exposure],0))}
 
ELSE 0
END
)
,0)


Can you add the calculation tied to your parameter that defines if a deal is closed or open, or is this just a field in your data?

Do you want the average exposure ignoring the null values? Or do you want the average exposure treating null exposures as actually having zero exposure? That is, does null mean unknown or does it mean zero?  Aggregation functions like AVG() automatically ignore null values

“COUNTD([Buyback]) > 0” means that at least one data row had a non-null value in the [Buyback] field. For that, you can use COUNT() instead of COUNTD(). Its more efficient and clarifies your intent

Do you really require an LOD calc? If Customer, Deal and Schedule are already the dimensions in your viz - i.e. on some non-filter shelf - then using an LOD is unnecessary complexity
